# Doctrine connect to redis WITH password

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, redis

Sounds simple but its had me going for hours on end.

How can I connect to a redis cache server using a password. It connects and caches doctrine queries successfully without a password but when I put a password it throws an exception

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309:
Unrecognized option "password" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.default.query_cache_driver"
```

I have tried a combination but my current code is
config.yml
.....

```
    entity_managers:
        default:
            metadata_cache_driver: apc
            query_cache_driver:
                type: redis
                host: localhost
                port: 6379
#                password: myStr0nG!passw0rd - adding this causes exception
                instance_class: Redis
            result_cache_driver:
                type: redis
                host: localhost
                port: 6379
#                password: myStr0nG!passw0rd - adding this causes exception
                instance_class: Redis
```

Comment: hey Don Omondi could you please tell me wish driver is the best wether array, redis, apc memcache??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot set password for the cache driver as its not supported.

If you want an alternative, consider using [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle)

Example config

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        cache:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://secret@localhost/1
            logging: %kernel.debug%
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default          # the name of your entity_manager connection
            document_manager: default        # the name of your document_manager connection
        result_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: [default, read]  # you may specify multiple entity_managers
        query_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
```

Comment: And https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SymfonyBridgeAdapter.php#L120 is why you can't set the password.

Comment: @Vamsi Thanks for your answer. I had looked at this bundle earlier but was not keen to take it up because it involved changing my controller's code which would make switching from redis to memcached or any other difficult. I guess I have no option now.

Comment: @user2268997 So if I were to hack that file and manually input my password where it says password => null would it work?

Comment: It should, but please don't cause it will demolish maintainability, I suggest you install doctrine-cache-bundle, create a redis cache, and pass it to the configuration as a `service` type cache.i.e: pass the service created by doctrine cache bundle to doctrine bundle.also in the documentation of [doctrine cache bundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle) there is no support for a password for a redis cache, but I took a look at the code and you should be able to pass the password in the `password` key of that cache configuration.

Comment: @user2268997 Good points and advice. I am not a fan of installing many bundles especially when the Standard edition comes with similar builtin functionality but in this particular case I have decided to go with the SncRedisBundle mentioned in Vamsi's answer that I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

To use password without Snc bundle, just use doctrine_cache entry:

Add DoctrineCacheBundle on AppKernel:

```
$bundles = [
    ...
    new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle(),
    ...
];
```

config.yml

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        my_provider:
            redis:
                host: hostname
                port: 6379
                password: foobared
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine_cache.providers.my_provider
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem at the similar way as [rogeriolino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979300/rogeriolino) did.

Here is a part of config relevant to current problem:

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        result_cache_driver:
          type: service
          id: "app.my_redis"
        metadata_cache_driver:
          type: service
          id: "app.my_redis"
        query_cache_driver:
          type: service
          id: "app.my_redis"
```

service.yml

```
services:
    app.my_redis:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\Cache\MyRedis
```

Service Class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Utils\Cache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache;


class MyRedis extends RedisCache
{
    private $password = 'some string you like but that passes';
    private $host = "some ip address";
    private $port = 6379;
    private $timeout = 0.0;
    private $dbNumber = 1;
    private $dbMap = [
        'local.windows.domain',
        'production.domain',
        'staging.domain',
    ];

    /**
     * MyRedis constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $redis = new \Redis;
        $redis->connect($this->host, $this->port, $this->timeout);
        $redis->auth($this->password);
        // This way of $_SERVER checking could be solved better.
        $redis->select(array_search($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $this->dbMap));
        $this->setRedis($redis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still has problems with it nowadays, you can supply the connection string with user and password in DSN format, like:

```
# DSN format
redis://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT

# example
redis://redis_username:redis_password@redis-hostname-or-ip.com:6379
```

This way you can, for example, define the default redis provider in Symfony

```
# 'config/packages/cache.yaml'
framework:
    cache:
        # better handle secrets via ENV vars, like: %env(resolve:REDIS_DSN)%
        default_redis_provider: 'redis://redis_username:redis_password@redis-hostname-or-ip.com:6379'
```